# Remove php file extension as well as have _GET param in a directory format

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know this question is asked for many times but I am not getting the proper solution for my condition probably because lack of knowledge about this code.

So far I am using the following code to hide the extension of the php file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

When I navigate through an url like this: `http://example.com/solutions` for `http://example.com/solutions.php` it works pretty good.

But when I want to use the url with `_GET` like this: `http://example.com/solutions/page_slug`

where the `page_slug` is a `_GET` param say `?slug=page_slug` ... then at that time it generates `404` not found `error` because it is considering the page_slug as file in solutions directory.

So I want that it should treat the first param in the url as filename and then upto two param as get param for example: `http://example.com/solutions_file/param1_page_slug/param2_any_other_param_may_be_id`

And if there are more than two param then the url structure would be normal for example if url like this:

`http://example.com/solutions_file/param1_page_slug/param2_any_other_param_may_be_id/param3_this_is_extra`

so then us url structure like this:

`http://example.com/solutions_file?param1=page_slug&param2=any_other_param_may_be_id&param3=this_is_extra&param4=and_so_on`

So this is all about I am trying to achieve, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a specific rule for each one of those:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# for just the php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /$1.php [L]

# for 1 param
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$1.php?slug=$2 [L,QSA]

# for 2 params
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$1.php?slug=$2&param2=$3 [L,QSA]

# for 3 params
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$1.php?slug=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4 [L,QSA]
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks this worked and for more than 3 param I can manually pass the query string. Thanks a lot :)